# Bolt dynamic route requirement

Tags: php, symfony, routes, silex, bolt-cms

How do I add a dynamic route requirement to a Bolt route.

I'm defining my route as follows:

```
formpages:
    path: '/{contenttypeslug}/{slug}'
    defaults:
        _controller: 'Bolt\Extension\Mahango\Forms\Extension::record'
    requirements:
        contenttypeslug: 'page'
        slug: 'Bolt\Extension\Mahango\Forms\Extension\Routing::getSlugRequirement'
```

In my `getSlugRequirement()` method I want to query the database to get a subset of page records but I don't have access to the `$app` var when the method is being called.

I've looked at the core code and tried to use `$app->mount('', new Bolt\Extension\Mahango\Forms\Extension\Routing());` in my `bootstrap.php` but here the extension hasn't yet been initialised.

How can I do get this to work?